Numerical Stiffness Issue in NDSolve for Stiff ODE System: How to Avoid Extrapolation Errors?
I am trying to solve a stiff system of ode differential equations (ODEs) using NDSolve in Wolfram Mathematica. The problem is related to modeling the dynamics of proteins over time, with parameters that seem to introduce considerable stiffness and singularities in the solution.
I have defined, calculated the derivative, and plotted the potential
w[un_] = -((b  d - e  q)/(2  b))^2   1/(e + 
      b   un^2) - ((q^2 + 8   b   c   m^2)/(4  b))  un^2 + c   un^4
dw = D[w[un], un]
Plot[w[un], {un, -10, 10}]



a = 2;
j = 2;
L = 200;
b = -0.0003070816340;
c = 0.4461893869;
d = 0.01142581922;
e = 0.0007675000601;
q = -0.003704049149;
m = 1.423206983;
delta = 0.05;
h = 1;
grid = Range[-L/2, L/2, h];
k = Length[grid];
deltaHat = h*delta;
var = Table[u[i][t], {i, k}];

eqs = Table[
   u[i]''[t] - (u[i + 1][t] + u[i - 1][t] - 2  u[i][t]) + 
     deltaHat  u[i]'[t] - (-(((8  b  c  m^2 + q^2)  u[i][t])/(2 b)) + 
       4 c u[i][t]^3 + ((b d - e q)^2 u[i][t])/(
       2 b (e + b u[i][t]^2)^2)) == 0, {i, 2, k - 1}];

bc = {u[1][t] == 0, u[k][t] == 0};
ic = Join[
   Thread[var == a*Sin[2*j*Pi*grid/L]] /. t -> 0, 
   Table[u[i]'[0] == 0, {i, 2, k - 1}]
];
tmax = 500;

sol = NDSolve[
   Join[eqs, {u[1]'[t] == 0, u[k]'[t] == 0}, ic], 
   var, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
   MaxStepFraction -> 1/500, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 8, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 8
];

{ListPlot[Transpose[{grid, var /. sol[[1]] /. t -> 0}], 
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(n\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(n\)]\)"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Initial Positions at t = 0", 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Medium]}], 
 Show[ListPlot[Transpose[{grid, var /. sol[[1]] /. t -> tmax}], 
   FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(n\)]\)", 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(n\)]\)"}, PlotLabel -> "", 
   PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[Medium]}],
   ListLinePlot[
   Transpose[{grid, 
     var /. sol[[1]] /. t -> tmax}], {PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}}]]}

This indicates that the input time exceeds the interpolation range computed by NDSolve, suggesting that it could not proceed effectively up to t = 500 without extrapolation. I tried adjusting the solver settings, such as increasing precision and reducing the maximum time, but the issue persists.
My Questions:

Are there any other methods or solver options I could try to better handle this stiffness? For example, would using "ImplicitRungeKutta" or a custom Method option provide better stability?
Are there known best practices for handling stiffness in ODEs involving complex boundary conditions and non-linear terms like mine?
Can I identify where exactly the stiffness or singularity is occurring so I can modify the equations or discretize them to reduce these issues?


The components of vars with positions {{26}, {76}, {126}, {176}} seem to develop a vertical asymptote at the point where the integration stops.

Is this system taken from the paper?

@AlexTrounev I am trying, based on this specific paper, https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.106.078102 to apply the conclusions I drew about DNA to my research and to proteins. Specifically, if the potential, as given to us by the paper, is differentiated and then placed into the discrete Klein-Gordon equation chain, I want to see if it yields the desired results

@AthanasiosParaskevopoulos Please, see my answer for soliton 1 from the specific paper.

To reproduce soliton 1 from the paper, we use code
U = -((b d - e q)/(2 b))^2/(e + 
     b k^2) - (q^2 + 8 b c m^2)/(4 b) k^2 + c k^4; 
D[U, k] /. k -> u[i][t]

(*Out[]= -(((8 b c m^2 + q^2) u[i][t])/(2 b)) + 
 4 c u[i][t]^3 + ((b d - e q)^2 u[i][t])/(2 b (e + b u[i][t]^2)^2)*)

(*soliton-1*){b, c, d , e, q, m1, m2} = { 1.800314201  10^-4 ,
    0.4222887366, 7.02765265  10^-3, 
   4.663610215  10^-4 , -2.190120515  10^-3, 1.444455611, 1.565166201};


a = Pi/2;
j = 2;
L = 200;
m = m1;
delta = 0.01999385999;
h = 1;
grid = Range[-L/2, L/2, h];
k = Length[grid];
deltaHat = h*delta;
var = Table[u[i][t], {i, k}];

eqs = Table[
   u[i]''[t] - (u[i + 1][t] + u[i - 1][t] - 2*u[i][t]) + 
     deltaHat*u[i]'[t] + -(((8 b c m^2 + q^2) u[i][t])/(2 b)) + 
     4 c u[i][t]^3 + ((b d - e q)^2 u[i][t])/(
     2 b (e + b u[i][t]^2)^2) == 0, {i, 2, k - 1}];

bc = {u[1][t] == 0, u[k][t] == 0};
ic = Join[Thread[var == a*Sin[j*Pi*grid/L]] /. t -> 0, 
   Table[u[i]'[0] == 0, {i, 2, k - 1}]];
tmax = 100; sol = 
 NDSolve[Join[eqs, {u[1]'[t] == 0, u[k]'[t] == 0}, ic], 
  var, {t, 0, tmax}, Method -> {"LinearlyImplicitEuler"}, 
  StartingStepSize -> 0.01];

Visualization
{ListPlot[Transpose[{grid, var /. sol[[1]] /. t -> 0}], 
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(n\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(n\)]\)"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Initial Positions at t = 0", 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Medium]}], 
 Show[ListPlot[Transpose[{grid, var /. sol[[1]] /. t -> tmax}], 
   FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(n\)]\)", 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(n\)]\)"}, PlotLabel -> "", 
   PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[Medium]}],
   ListLinePlot[
   Transpose[{grid, 
     var /. sol[[1]] /. t -> tmax}], {PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}}]]}



Although the proteins are more complicated, the solutions have four zero points as in DNA for h=2. I tried it and soliton-2 produces identical solutions only when m1 produces a slightly more differential solution. It's amazing how similar they are, though.

@AthanasiosParaskevopoulos Could you add other solutions from Table 1 to your question using my code?

I posted an answer about the behavior of soliton-2 for m1 and m2

@AthanasiosParaskevopoulos Thank you very much (+1). Now answer looks as complete.

(*soliton - 
   2*) {b, c, d, e, q, m1, m2} = {-2.22159366  10^-4, 1.088046084, 
    1.308858509 10^-3, 3.94423507 10^-4, -6.4844084 10^-4, 
    1.518466566, 1.543914339};


a = Pi/2;
j = 2;
L = 200;
m = m1;
delta = 0.01999385999;
h = 2;
grid = Range[-L/2, L/2, h];
k = Length[grid];
deltaHat = h*delta;
var = Table[u[i][t], {i, k}];

eqs = Table[
   u[i]''[t] - (u[i + 1][t] + u[i - 1][t] - 2*u[i][t]) + 
     deltaHat*u[i]'[t] + -(((8 b c m^2 + q^2) u[i][t])/(2 b)) + 
     4 c u[i][
        t]^3 + ((b d - e q)^2 u[i][t])/(2 b (e + b u[i][t]^2)^2) == 
    0, {i, 2, k - 1}];

bc = {u[1][t] == 0, u[k][t] == 0};
ic = Join[Thread[var == a*Sin[j*Pi*h*grid/L]] /. t -> 0, 
   Table[u[i]'[0] == 0, {i, 2, k - 1}]];
tmax = 100; sol = 
 NDSolve[Join[eqs, {u[1]'[t] == 0, u[k]'[t] == 0}, ic], 
  var, {t, 0, tmax}, Method -> {"LinearlyImplicitEuler"}, 
  StartingStepSize -> 0.01];

Visualization
{ListPlot[Transpose[{grid, var /. sol[[1]] /. t -> 0}], 
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(n\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(n\)]\)"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Initial Positions at t = 0", 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Medium]}], 
 Show[ListPlot[Transpose[{grid, var /. sol[[1]] /. t -> tmax}], 
   FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(n\)]\)", 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(n\)]\)"}, PlotLabel -> "", 
   PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[Medium]}],
   ListLinePlot[
   Transpose[{grid, 
     var /. sol[[1]] /. t -> tmax}], {PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}}]]}

The plot for m1

The plot for m2

